# JS automatically adding commas

Tags: javascript

When I get the information from the API, i want my output to automatically have comma's `($279127832954 -> $279,127,832,954)`. Normally I use `.toLocaleString()` but that didnt work seem to work.

My javsscript code:

```
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/", function(data) {      
$("#totalalt_market_cap_usd").html("$" + (data.total_market_cap_usd / 100).toFixed() * (100 -data.bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap).toFixed());          
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `toFixed.toLocaleString()` ? . You mean `toFixed().toLocaleString()` ?

Comment: Edited @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to be doing `.toFixed()` instead of `toFixed` as it is a method and not a property. Then `.toLocaleString()` seems to work fine.

See the code below:

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/", function(data) {
  var val = (data.total_market_cap_usd / 100).toFixed() * (100 - data.bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap).toFixed();
  val = val.toLocaleString();
  $("#totalalt_market_cap_usd").html("$" + val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="totalalt_market_cap_usd"></div>
```